# Listen to objects click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to listen to both "button" and "a" click, and then pass the value of the attribute "name" to a variable, I can't find what's wrong with my code:

```
$('a').click(function() {
var anchor;
anchor=$(this).attr('name');
$('#linkPressed').val(anchor);
});

$('button').click(function() {
var anchor;
anchor=$(this).attr('name');
$('#linkPressed').val(anchor);
});
```

**Update:** I have a PHP script that do something different according to the "linkPressed" value. Seemingly, this code is applicable also for `<a>` and `<button>` that don't have `"name"` attribute, which ruins my script. Is there a way to exclude the objects that don't have `"name"` attribute from the "click listener"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code itself. Please post your HTML and where you place the code in the document.

Comment: Is your code inside the `$(document).ready()` handler? If not, you need to move it there.

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with what you've written.

Comment: please put your html code also

Comment: You are looking for the attribute selector: `a[name]` http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only select elements that have an attribute `name`, use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('a[name], button[name]').click(...);
// or
$('a, button').filter('[name]').click(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can separate your selectors using comma `,`. It's probably not working because you've initialize `anchor` variable two times:

```
$('a, button').click(function() {
    var anchor;
    anchor=$(this).attr('name');
    $('#linkPressed').val(anchor);
});
```

Comment: I think that anchor variable is local scope.

Comment: i think variable anchor are differents in both function. it is not that what OP want.

Comment: @AwladLiton: It looks to me that the code of both event handlers is exactly the same.

Comment: yes that is. but i think  it is not the solution of OP question :)

Comment: @AwladLiton: I believe it's what the OP wants, but that alone won't solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the handler only to elements with `name` attributes:

```
$('a[name], button[name]').click(function() {
    $('#linkPressed').val(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use multiple selector by the `,` at a one time it remove repetitive code

may be `#linkPressed` is a tag type not a input type at that time use `text()` at the palace of `val()`

```
$('a,button').click(function() {
var anchor;
anchor=$(this).attr('name');
$('#linkPressed').val(anchor);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it.

```
$("a, button").click(function() {
    var anchor;

    if($(this).attr("name") != undefined) {
         anchor=$(this).attr('name');
         $('#linkPressed').val(anchor);
    }
});
```